# Axon 4 kafka how to invoke eventhandler

Tags: spring, kotlin, axon

i'm studying axon. i want to make simple axon app with kafka and mongodb.

i'm using

1. two instances (command app, query app)
2. mongodb and kafka without axon server
3. kotlin
4. multi-module
5. axon framework 4.5

i checked command app that storing event data to mongodb.

However event handler not invoked.

here is project structure

```
practice-root
│
├── command
│   ├── build
│   ├── src
│   │    ├── main
│   │    │     ├ kotlin
│   │    │     │  └ com.cqrs.axon
│   │    │     │         ├ Application.kt
│   │    │     │         ├ SimpleDTO
│   │    │     │         ├ SimpleController
│   │    │     │         ...
│   │    │     └ resources
│   │    ├── test
│   │    │
│   └── build.gradle
│
├── query
│     ├ ...
│     ...
│
├── common
│     ├ ...
│     ...
│
├── README
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

here is my code

**command module**

Application.kt

```
@SpringBootApplication()
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

SimpleService.kt

```
@Service
class SimpleService(
    private val eventGateway: EventGateway
) {
    @CommandHandler
    fun createSimple(simpleDTO: SimpleDTO): Unit {
        return this.eventGateway.publish(
            SimpleEvent(
                id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                data = simpleDTO.data
            )
        )
    }
}
```

SimpleDTO.kt

```
data class SimpleDTO (
    val data: String
)
```

SimpleController.kt

```
@RestController
class SimpleController(
    private val simpleService: SimpleService
    ) {

    @PostMapping("/simple")
    fun createSimple(@RequestBody simpleDTO: SimpleDTO): Unit {
        return simpleService.createSimple(simpleDTO)
    }
}
```

AxonConfig.kt

```
@Configuration
class AxonConfig {


    @Bean
    fun eventStore(storageEngine: EventStorageEngine, configuration: AxonConfiguration): EmbeddedEventStore {
    return EmbeddedEventStore.builder()
        .storageEngine(storageEngine)
        .messageMonitor(configuration.messageMonitor(EventStore::class.java, "eventStore"))
        .build()
    }


    @Bean
    fun storageEngine(client: MongoClient): EventStorageEngine {
        return MongoEventStorageEngine.builder()
            .mongoTemplate(DefaultMongoTemplate.builder().mongoDatabase(client).build()).build()
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Kafka producer factory, using the Kafka properties configured in resources/application.yml
     */
    @Bean
    fun producerFactory(kafkaProperties: KafkaProperties): ProducerFactory<String, ByteArray> {
        return DefaultProducerFactory.builder<String, ByteArray>()
            .configuration(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties())
            .producerCacheSize(10_000)
            .confirmationMode(ConfirmationMode.WAIT_FOR_ACK)
            .build()
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
---
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: commandSpringApplication
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://user:u123@localhost:27016/test?authSource=admin
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

axon:
  axonserver:
    enabled: false
  kafka:
    client-id: myproducer
    default-topic: axon-events
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      event-processor-mode: tracking
      transaction-id-prefix: sample-eventstx

    properties:
      security.protocol: PLAINTEXT

logging:
  level:
    com:
      cqrs:
        command: debug
    org:
      axonframework: debug
```

**query module**

Application.kt

```
@SpringBootApplication()
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

QuerySimpleProjection.kt

```
@Component
@ProcessingGroup("SampleProcessor")
class QuerySimpleProjection (
    private val simpleRepository: QuerySimpleRepository
) {

    @EventHandler
    fun on(event: SimpleEvent, @Timestamp instant: Instant) {
        val simpleMV = SimpleMV(
            id = event.id,
            data = event.data
        )
        simpleRepository.save(simpleMV)
    }
}
```

QuerySimpleRepository.kt

```
@Repository
interface QuerySimpleRepository : JpaRepository<SimpleMV, String>
```

SimpleMV.kt

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mv_simple_mongo")
data class SimpleMV (

    @Id
    val id: String,
    val data: String
)
```

AxonConfig.kt

```
@Configuration
class AxonConfig {

    @Autowired
    fun configureStreamableKafkaSource(configurer: EventProcessingConfigurer,
                                       streamableKafkaMessageSource: StreamableKafkaMessageSource<String, ByteArray>
    ) {
        configurer.registerTrackingEventProcessor("SampleProcessor") { streamableKafkaMessageSource }
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
---
server:
  port: 9090

spring:
  application:
    name: queryMongoSpringApplication
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:33060/test?useSSL=false&characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true
    username: user
    password: u123

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
        hbm2ddl.auto: update
        format_sql: true
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC


axon:
  axonserver:
    enabled: false
  kafka:
    client-id: myconsumer
    default-topic: axon-events
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      event-processor-mode: tracking

    properties:
      security.protocol: PLAINTEXT


logging:
  level:
    com:
      cqrs:
        command: debug
    org:
      axonframework: debug
```

**common module**

SimpleEvent.kt

```
data class SimpleEvent (
    val id: String,
    val data: String
)
```

build.gradle of command module and query module

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-jpa'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-allopen'
...
dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients'
    implementation 'org.axonframework.extensions.kafka:axon-kafka-spring-boot-starter:4.5.3'
    compile "org.axonframework:axon-spring-boot-starter:4.5.8", {
        exclude group:'org.axonframework', module: 'axon-server-connector'
    }
    implementation "org.axonframework:axon-configuration:4.5.8"
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

query, common, command app package names are same - com.cqrs.axon

Please let me know..

or please recommand other example project with multiple module and kafka, mongodb(or mysql).

i see kafka-extension-example a lot but still very confusing how to use axon

Comment: Have you checked whether the events are actually carried over from MongoDb to your Kafka topic? Knowing this will help greatly, because it deduces whether the issue resides with the event Publisher end of your app or the event Consumer end.

Comment: yes kafka topic get message. but still can't invoke eventhandler

Comment: That's good to know, thanks newoneim.
In all honesty, I don't see anything obvious right away in your setup. Do you perhaps have a repository containing the above so that I/somebody can run it locally?

Comment: To give an idea what I would do with such a sample project. I'd start the query app up and debug through it. I'd make sure that the Kafka Message Source is present, that it's configured for the right Event Processor, that the Event Processor is started, and that the `QuerySimpleProjection` is created.